# Linear recurrence sequence in F2

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations

Currently, I'm solving this exercise:

Let $s=  (s_0,s_1,s_2,...)$  be  a  linear  recurrence  sequence  in $F_2$ with  recurrent relation $s_{n+3}+s_{n+1}+s_n= 0$, for $n\in \mathbb N$.

Now my (simple) question: What's the period of the relation?

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: What have you done to try to answer this question? Given the values of $s_0,s_1,s_2$, what is the values of $s_3,s_4,s_5$ for example?

Answer (score 1):

(EDITED) Hint: if $s_k = s_0$, $s_{k+1} = s_1$, and $s_{k+2} = s_2$, the sequence will be periodic with period $k$.

Comment: Yes, and the key here seems to be that in $F_2$ we have $x+x=0$ (it is easy to overlook that $F_2$ assumption).

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it... let's say the initial state is $s_0 = s_1 = s_2 = 1$. What's the recurrence then, when the period is $k$?

Comment: If $s_0 = s_1 = s_2 = 1$, then I get $s_7 = s_8 = s_9 = 1$, so the period is $7$.